# AppFabric - Etw - Unable to unregister the trace provider

Tags: .net, wcf, appfabric, etw

We're using AppFabric Monitoring to inspect execution timings and to track log messages. This works pretty well since one year, but a few servers have *suddenly* stopped to monitor our WCF services.

I have a little experience with AppFabric Monitoring and I have isolated the problem to Event Collector Service (checklist available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh351427%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)).

Basically, the service is running but can not register to the trace session.
The service is running under a specific domain account and the same configuration works on another servers.

Here are the event Logs
[image: event logs]

> **EventID 146** Unable to unregister the trace provider: {f6fb79f7-0ee0-4e3c-9eac-cccdaea5dc2b} for event trace session:
>   'AppFabric Event Collector Session(Name [] - Collector [0] - Session
>   Id [4f880754-d52d-4e29-ab99-3a3fab65f4ee])'. Error code: 87
>
> **EventID 101** Unable to configure and start the event trace session 'AppFabric Event Collector Session(Name [] - Collector [0] - Session
>   Id [4f880754-d52d-4e29-ab99-3a3fab65f4ee])'. Detailed
>   information:Access is denied.
>
> **EventID 135** Event Trace process failed for event trace session 'AppFabric Event Collector Session(Name [] - Collector [0] - Session
>   Id [4f880754-d52d-4e29-ab99-3a3fab65f4ee])' listener stopped. Error
>   code : 4201.
>
> **EventID 121** Unable to add event source '{f6fb79f7-0ee0-4e3c-9eac-cccdaea5dc2b}' to event trace session
>   'AppFabric Event Collector Session(Name [] - Collector [0] - Session
>   Id [4f880754-d52d-4e29-ab99-3a3fab65f4ee])'.  Error code: 87

Ok, there may be a security issue. I've check all items in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh351427%28v=azure.10%29.aspx), with no success.

Is there any way to fix this or to get additional logs/details ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh351424%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) and checking with system admin, it seems that the specific does not belongs to "Performance Monitor Users" group. That's all